# Flutter contenedor con scroll

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, flutter, dart

estoy intentando hacer Scroll en un carro de compras en una app de flutter, pero por más codigo que intente el contenedor no se mueve, dejo el código.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: Helper.of(context).onWillPop,
  child: Scaffold(
    key: _con.scaffoldKey,
    bottomNavigationBar: CartBottomDetailsWidget(con: _con),
    appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (widget.routeArgument != null) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(widget.routeArgument.param, arguments: RouteArgument(id: widget.routeArgument.id));
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
          }
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        S.of(context).cart,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.merge(TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3)),
      ),
    ),
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _con.refreshCarts,
      child: _con.carts.isEmpty
          ? EmptyCartWidget()
          : Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
              children: [
                ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          S.of(context).shopping_cart,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          S.of(context).verify_your_quantity_and_click_checkout,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListView.separated(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      primary: true,
                      itemCount: _con.carts.length,
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return SizedBox(height: 15);
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return CartItemWidget(
                          cart: _con.carts.elementAt(index),
                          heroTag: 'cart',
                          increment: () {
                            _con.incrementQuantity(_con.carts.elementAt(index));
                          },
                          decrement: () {
                            _con.decrementQuantity(_con.carts.elementAt(index));
                          },
                          onDismissed: () {
                            _con.removeFromCart(_con.carts.elementAt(index));
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.15), offset: Offset(0, 2), blurRadius: 5.0)]),
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    onSubmitted: (String value) {
                      _con.doApplyCoupon(value);
                    },
                    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    controller: TextEditingController()..text = coupon?.code ?? '',
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                      suffixText: coupon?.valid == null ? '' : (coupon.valid ? S.of(context).validCouponCode : S.of(context).invalidCouponCode),
                      suffixStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: _con.getCouponIconColor())),
                      suffixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.confirmation_number,
                          color: _con.getCouponIconColor(),
                          size: 28,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: S.of(context).haveCouponCode,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5))),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

El capture es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debajo del tercer elemento hay un 4 elemento en el carrito pero no se puede hacer scroll, he intentado con `physics, expanded` etc

¿Alguna sugerencia de porque el elemento a pesar de que lo hago scrollable no detecta el touch?

Comment: Replica el layout solo con bloques simples, eso te ayudará a que detectes el problema con mayor rapidez, una vez que tengas eso, pones el código y te ayudaremos :)

Answer (score 0):

Haz probado usando un Scrollbar?

por ejemplo

```
    Scrollbar( 
    controller: _scrollController //Lo defines tu
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    child: SingleChildScrollView( scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    controller: _scrollController,
    child:
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Vendría genial que explicaras lo que hace tu código tanto para el OP como para personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.